# Are the PopVision System Analyser and Graph Analyser open source?

Tags: ipu

As from the title, are the PopVision System Analyser and Graph Analyser open source? I couldn't find them on Github so I'm assuming they aren't, but I'm asking here to be 100% sure.

The reason I'm asking is, I noticed a non-intuitive feature of the System Analyser and wanted to raise an issue.

Answer (score 1):

They are not open source and I do not believe there are plans to open source them currently.

I'm sure they'd love to hear your feedback and ideas though to improve their product. https://support.graphcore.ai

Answer (score 0):

The PopVision tools are not open sourced but are released on Github.

- https://github.com/graphcore/popvision_system_analyser
- https://github.com/graphcore/popvision_graph_analyser